# SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Tags: javascript

```
$('.pagination ul li').each({ 
if( $(this).index(this) > 2  )
{
   $(this).hide();
}
 });
```

SyntaxError: missing : after property id whats the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure `$(this).index(this)` will get what you want.

Comment: What version of jquery are you running?  There was a bug related to this syntax in 1.8.0.  It was fixed in 1.8.1

Comment: @gabaum10: What bug are you referring to?

Comment: Oh wait, misread the question.  Thought it was referring to a bug I saw with the new selector engine.

Answer (score 12):

Use the keyword `function` preceding `{}` or it will be interpreted as an object literal.

```
$('.pagination ul li').each(function() { 
    if ($(this).index(this) > 2) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Also, `$(this).index(this)` does not do what you expect. Did you want to check if the index at which the element is located is greater than 2? Use this revision instead:

```
$('.pagination ul li').each(function(idx) { 
    if (idx > 2) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass `.each` a `function`.  Without the `function()`, it's being read as an object (`{}`).

```
$('.pagination ul li').each(function(){ 
    if($(this).index(this) > 2){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

P.S. `$(this).index(this)` does not do what you think it does.  It will search inside `this` for `this`, therefore it always returns `0`.

If you want the index of the `li` in the `ul`, use the index parameter from the `.each`.

```
$('.pagination ul li').each(function(index){ 
    if(index > 2){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

P.P.S. If all you want to do is hide the `li`s that have an `index > 2`, then you can do this even easier:

```
$('.pagination ul li:gt(2)').hide();
```